# Why my curl gets stuck at getting anything from some domains?

Tags: curl

My `curl` hangs when I want to curl some websites. For example for **GitHub**, the `curl -vvv https://github.com` output is:

```
*   Trying 140.82.121.4:443...
* Connected to github.com (140.82.121.4) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

But it's OK when I connect to some other sites.

What should I do? What is wrong here?

Comment: Maybe old ca certs. What if you add -k option?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the same case.
I was running WSL2 using a VPN client enabled on host. The curl command inside WSL2 hangs for some domains (like youtube.com) and it runs well for other domains (like google.com). It turns out the reason is the MTU size gap between VM interface and host interface. Check the solution here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4698#issuecomment-871279847